# Dash Pandas Generate descriptive statistics Table

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a dataset which is similar to below one. Please note that there are multiple values for a single ID.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME':pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-05 23:00:00',freq='h'),
                   'Line1':[random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(120)],
                   'Line2':[random.uniform(60, 100) for n in range(120)],
                   'ID':[random.randrange(1, 100) for n in range(120)],
                   'TIMEINTERVAL':[random.randrange(1, 200) for n in range(120)]})

df['VISIT'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['VISIT']==1, df['VISIT'].isin([2,3])], ['New', 'InProgress'], 'Done')
```

I use the following DASH code to make descriptive stats table.

```
df = df.describe()

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns],
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

But, I cannot see the column that comes when using describe method in pandas: e.g. std,mean, and so on. How should I twist my code so that I cann see those?

Comment: Try this: `df.reset_index(inplace=True)`

Comment: @r-beginners it did not work. I get the same result

Comment: What version of plotly are you currently using?

Comment: @r-beginners Once I run the notebook, I keep getting 403 error and nothings show.

Comment: I use plotly 5.11.0

Comment: If you click the link in the comment and get a 403, is Colab allowed in your environment?

Comment: Yes, Colab is allowed in my environment. The error pops up when I run the Dash part of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is displayed by resetting the index of the data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME':pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-05 23:00:00',freq='h'),
                   'Line1':[random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(120)],
                   'Line2':[random.uniform(60, 100) for n in range(120)],
                   'ID':[random.randrange(1, 100) for n in range(120)],
                   'TIMEINTERVAL':[random.randrange(1, 200) for n in range(120)]})

df['VISIT'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['VISIT']==1, df['VISIT'].isin([2,3])], ['New', 'InProgress'], 'Done')

df = df.describe()

df.reset_index(inplace=True)

from dash import Dash, dash_table
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash

#app = Dash(__name__)
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
    
app.layout = dash_table.DataTable(
    data=df.to_dict('records'),
    columns=[{'id': c, 'name': c} for c in df.columns],
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, mode='inline')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, with jupyter-dash it works. However, what is the best way to do it with Dash?

Comment: I tried running it in VSCode and it is always correct by resetting the index of the data frame.

Comment: My running environment is dash:2.6.1,plotly:5.10.1,pandas:1.3.5.

Comment: I use pycharm and edge to show output. I will try with another browser.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow I can also got it work with Dash.